# Scala Play Framework how to set language for current request?

Tags: scala, playframework

I know it is possible to set preferable language to session with code

```
Ok(views.html.index()).withLang(lang)
```

But it will work only on next request and on the current request user get page in default language.
I've tried make it possible like this:

```
implicit val lang = Lang("de")
Ok(views.html.index("Homepage"))
```

without success.
What is a correct way to achieve this?
Here is the view:

```
@(message: String)(implicit messages: Messages)

@main(message) {
    @messages("admin.area.enter")
}
```

Comment: I think you've answered your question by mistake. It should probably be an edit to this question. It's easy to edit this and delete the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Play 2.4 documentation on internationalization](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaI18N) states

"Also, Play knows out of the box how to inject a MessagesApi value (that uses the DefaultMessagesApi implementation), so you can just annotate your controller with the @javax.inject.Inject annotation and let Play automatically wire the components for you."

Something like this

*Controller:*

```
class FooController @Inject() (val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport {

  def index() = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }

}
```

*Template:*

```
@()(implicit messages: Messages, lang: Lang)

Messages says @messages("hello.msg")
```

If you wish to implement a language picker component then this answer might help

[Language selector in Play 2.4 & Scala 2.11.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824933/language-selector-in-play-2-4-scala-2-11-6)

Here is an example with a composite action which modifies the request header.

```
object LanguageAction extends ActionBuilder[Request] {
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {

  val newRequest = new WrappedRequest[A](request) {
      //calculate from request url
      val lang = Lang("fr")

      override lazy val acceptLanguages = Seq(lang)
    }

    block(newRequest)
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
class FooController @Inject() (val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport {

  def index() = LanguageAction { implicit request =>

    Ok(views.html.index())
  }

}
```

View:

```
@()(implicit messages: Messages, lang: Lang)

@messages("foo.bar")
```